# & use in Sass for specific tag

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I want to use the & (which refers to a class) in combination with a tag. Like this example:

```
.back {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: blue;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
   }
}
```

I want only to use the hover for a-tags. The following is not possible

```
a&:hover {
     color: red;
}
```

Does anybody know this?

Comment: No, the `&` can't be used that way.  The error you get when you try to use it that way says so:  "&" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.

Comment: I've attempted to run the same thing they have in their documentation, but get the same error: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just don't need the `&`:

```
.back {
  ...

  a:hover {
    color: red;
 }
```

}

In sass, this will compile to `.back a:hover { color:red; }`. You don't need the &, as this is used to further extend the `back` class, which I don't think you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
.back {
  ...
}

a.back:hover {
  color: red
}
```

Comment: That works of course, but I want to know if there is a solution like the way I described